# Logging into Ebay using Python Sel

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to log into ebay using Python Selenium Chromedriver but having some difficulty.

```
driver.get("https://signin.ebay.co.uk/ws/eBayISAPI.dll")
driver.maximize_window()

email_address = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@placeholder='Email or username']")
password = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@placeholder='Password']")

email_address.send_keys("email")
password.send_keys("password")
```

The error is that the element is not visible:

```
raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotVisibleException: Message: element not visible
```

It should be fairly straight forward but I can't figure it out. On similiar issues I've had before it was something to do with iframes.

Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two elements matching with the given XPATH.

Try the following code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

driver = webdriver.Chrome();

driver.get("https://signin.ebay.co.uk/ws/eBayISAPI.dll")
driver.maximize_window()

email_address = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span/input[@placeholder='Email or username']")
password = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span/input[@placeholder='Password']")

email_address.send_keys("email")
password.send_keys("password")
```

Comment: Many thanks Naveen! That is working now. So I was just missing the span before the input?

Comment: Yes, made more specific XPATH